# How to replace multiple placeholders in string with array values?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a string which looks like this:

```
'I want a {Crust} crust {Type} pizza'
```

{Crust} and {Type} are placeholders in the string and I would like to replace the {Crust} and {Type} value with their actual values which are of type string array.

Crust-

```
['Pan','Thin','Tossed']
```

Type-

```
['Veggie','Pepperoni']
```

Expected Output should be all possible combinations for values from the array like below:

```
I want a Pan crust Veggie pizza
I want a Thin crust Veggie pizza
I want a Tossed crust Veggie pizza
I want a Pan crust Pepperoni pizza
I want a Thin crust Pepperoni pizza
I want a Tossed crust Pepperoni pizza
```

I'm looking for a more generic solution since I can have more values in Crust and Type array. Also, there can be a new placeholder, for example **{Delivery}** which would be replaced by another array of string **['For here','To go'].**

Answer (score 1):

You can do a replace on the strings

```js
const crusts = ['Pan','Thin','Tossed'];

const types = ['Veggie','Pepperoni'];

const output = 'I want a {Crust} crust {Type} pizza'.replace('{Crust}', crusts[2]).replace('{Type}', types[1]);

console.log(output);
```

But this has nothing to do with Angular, usually in Angular you would have a properties on your component called crust and type and then they would be displayed in the template with binding like

```
I want a {{crust}} crust {{type}} pizza
```

See this StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-prg9fx

Comment: I'm looking for a more generic solution than using hardcoded indices

Answer (score 0):

You can potentially use **template literals** (backticks)?

```
`I want ${Crust[key]} crust ${Type[key]} pizza`
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

You can try using nested for loops if you have just 2 combinations for more I suggest using backtracking.

```
const Crusts= ['Pan','Thin','Tossed'];

const Types = ['Veggie','Pepperoni'];
for(const Crust of Crusts){
   for(const Type of Types){
    console.log(`I want ${Crust} crust ${Type} pizza`);
   }
}
```

Comment: There can be multiple combinations, so using multiple for loops won't be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

This approach leverages `map` against each array and flattens the results producing an array of the desired strings:

```
Array.prototype.concat.apply([], 
    this.pizzaTypes.map(p => {
        return this.crusts.map(c => {
            return `I want a ${c} crust ${p} pizza.`;
        });
    })
);
```

**Update**:

You can nest as many arrays and flatten them appropriately if you want to have additional interpolated strings to your results.

```
crusts = ['Pan','Thin','Tossed'];
pizzaTypes = ['Veggie','Pepperoni'];
cheese = ['Feta','Mozzarella']

Array.prototype.concat.apply([],
        this.pizzaTypes.map(p => {
            return Array.prototype.concat.apply([],
                this.crusts.map(c => {
                    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([],
                        this.cheese.map(ch => {
                            return `I want a ${c} crust ${p} pizza with ${ch} cheese.`;
                        })
                    );
                })
            );
        })
    );
```

Produces this list:

- I want a Pan crust Veggie pizza with Feta cheese.

  I want a Pan crust Veggie pizza with Mozzarella cheese.

  I want a Thin crust Veggie pizza with Feta cheese.

  I want a Thin crust Veggie pizza with Mozzarella cheese.

  I want a Tossed crust Veggie pizza with Feta cheese.

  I want a Tossed crust Veggie pizza with Mozzarella cheese.

  I want a Pan crust Pepperoni pizza with Feta cheese.

  I want a Pan crust Pepperoni pizza with Mozzarella cheese.

  I want a Thin crust Pepperoni pizza with Feta cheese.

  I want a Thin crust Pepperoni pizza with Mozzarella cheese.

  I want a Tossed crust Pepperoni pizza with Feta cheese.

  I want a Tossed crust Pepperoni pizza with Mozzarella cheese.

HTH

Comment: Could you specify how the code would look like when there are multiple arrays instead of just two?

Comment: @AbhishekDhotre I've updated my answer with the response

Comment: Thanks, but I think the code would look a bit messy if the arrays are more than 5.

Comment: @AbhishekDhotre Of course! You can always make a function for this which would clean and make your code reusable. I'll leave that for you to explore. Good luck!